# parallel testing (testng.xml) for one module in multiple module project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, testng, teamcity

I'm trying to execute parallel tests only for particular module.
(Assume that the `testng.xml` file is configured correctly since debugging with intellij the particular module I can see in maven build/exe logs that the tests running in parallel)
 details:
[project module structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gth24.png)

When I add `testng.xml` to a specific module (e.g: `Module_3`), maven looks for testng.xml file in each module. Since there is only a `testng.xml` in `Module 3`, maven fails (e.g. Missing testng.xml in `Module 1`).
You can see the same behavior when I add testng.xml to the parent Module.

Is the answer is to locate dummy testng.xml files in all the other modules ? or there's better option ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you add the `testng.xml` file and more important where ?